# Codekit with RTLCSS hook

Tags: bash, sh, codekit

Is anyone face that problem before? which is when I'm using RTLCSS with Codekit hooks it not work and it telling me command not found but when Im using it in terminal it's work correctly.

The problem that shown to me inside Codekit is:
**/bin/sh: line 7: rtlcss: command not found**

```
set -x
MY_BUILD_PATHS=""
MY_BUILD_PATHS=$CK_PROJECT_ROOT"/build/css/main.css"
echo "$MY_BUILD_PATHS"
chmod +x "$MY_BUILD_PATHS"
o="${MY_BUILD_PATHS/.css/.rtl.css}"
rtlcss "$MY_BUILD_PATHS" "$o"
```

**and this my Codekit log:**

```
 The Hook "RTLCSS" exited with code 127 and wrote this to StdErr:

+ MY_BUILD_PATHS=
+ MY_BUILD_PATHS='/OneDrive/My Work/Model Jo/jo Website/build/css/main.css'
+ echo '/OneDrive/My Work/Model Jo/jo Website/build/css/main.css'
+ chmod +x '/OneDrive/My Work/Model Jo/jo Website/build/css/main.css'
+ o='/OneDrive/My Work/Model Jo/jo Website/build/css/main.rtl.css'
+ rtlcss '/OneDrive/My Work/Model Jo/jo Website/build/css/main.css' '/OneDrive/My Work/Model Jo/jo Website/build/css/main.rtl.css'
/bin/sh: line 7: rtlcss: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just have to specify the full disk path to rtlcss:

Instead of just `rtlcss`, like so: `/usr/local/bin/rtlcss`

I had a similar problem with postcss in CodeKit.